# How to POST backbone model data to DB through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backbone.js

I am trying to understand *localStorage*, but still a bit confused as It seems only few lines of code do a lot in the background.

What do I need to do to POST model data to a mySQL DB using PHP?

It seems `save()` does everything for you but where do I setup the connection to the DB, user, password...etc?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First localStorage is a HTML5 API, and it saves locally; while php is on the server.

There's a great [video by Jeffrey Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uykzCfu1RiQ) which explains how to set the routes, with use of Laravel as PHP Framework (but you can use anything).

If you're running Apache WebServer, or u can use `emulateJSON()` Backbone method, or u can set up [mod dav](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/es/mod/mod_dav.html) to enable PUT and DELETE method.

If u choose to to emulateJSON, the PUT and DELETE HTTP methods will be interpreted as POST method when it goes to the server.

I hope i've been explicit enough. if not so, feel free to ask.